# How to filter an array without losing data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have a function to filter an array of todos. The array is filtered correctly but when I type some thing else it removes other array elements and doesn't go back.

I've seen a few solutions, but they say "you have to write code in the render function" and I don't use this method because I render the array elsewhere with the help of props. `filteredTodos` has all local storage data.

How can I filter this data without losing data?

```
// *** Form.js ***
  const filterTodos = (e) => {
    const filtTod = filteredTodos.filter((todo) => {
      return todo.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    });
    setFilteredTodos([...filtTod]);
  };
```

```
// it's my render place *** TodoList.js ***
return (
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {filteredTodos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <Todo
            id={todo.id}
            key={todo.id}
            text={todo.text}
            completed={todo.completed}
            setTodos={setTodos}
            todos={todos}
          />
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

```
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]); // Todos is all array items.
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("all");
  const [filteredTodos, setFilteredTodos] = useState([]); // the state is for my filter list
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of reference array of todos? If you use one list for both the filtering and the original list, after one filter operation, you've irrevocably lost data. Use two lists: one to contain all the todos and another to contain only the filtered ones for display, generated dynamically based on the reference array of all todos.

Comment: @ggorlen I have but ı don't know how ı do it.

Comment: Please show your reference array as part of your component as a [mcve]. Likely, all you need is `filteredTodos.filter` => `allTodos.filter` or something like that.

Comment: @ggorlen Please can you write as an answer?

Comment: @ggorlen Okay, ı added all states. If you wanna other information about codes. Please tell me.

Comment: Thanks. `todos.filter` should be the only change necessary. If that's not it, please add a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, it's working! If you wanna create an answer for the change and explain. I could mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with filtering data like an array of todos is to maintain a consistent "reference" or "source" array that represents all of the todos that exist in your app. This reference array may change when the user adds or removes a todo item, and may be persisted to the backend (or local storage, in your case) in some capacity or other. This array is the source of truth.

When a user enters a search/filtering term, filter on the reference/source array of all todos every time rather than the already-filtered result set.

In your code, `todos` represents the source array and `filteredTodos` represents the results of a single search. By using `filteredTodos.filter`, the results either keep diminishing after each filtering query, or there never were any results to work with to begin with -- either way, it's incorrect.

Think of `filteredTodos` as a temporary snapshot of `todos` used to show a subset view of todos to match the user's search term.

The fix is to use `todos.filter` rather than `filteredTodos.filter` so that you're always searching on the full data set.